# Order Statistics Tree on top of Treap

Tags: python, algorithm, programming-challenge, python-3.x

I built an Order Statistics tree on top of a Treap in order to solve [this](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/median) HackerRank problem. It works (passed all test cases). Any comments whatsoever would be greatly appreciated.

```
class EmptyTreeError(Exception):
    def __init__(self):
        self.error = "Empty tree"

class node(object):
    def __init__(self,val,prty,prnt=None,lchild=None,rchild=None):
        self.prnt = prnt
        self.lchild = lchild
        self.rchild = rchild
        self.val = val
        self.prty = prty
        self.size = 1

    def __str__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return str((self.val,self.prty,self.size,(self.prnt.val,self.prnt.prty) if self.prnt else None))

    # size needs to be recalculated all the way up to the root on insertions and deletions
    def recalc_size(self):
        self.size = (self.lchild.size if self.lchild else 0) + (self.rchild.size if self.rchild else 0) + 1 

    # always need to keep track of the root because it potentially changes 
    def find_root(self):
        p = self
        while p.prnt != None: 
            p = p.prnt
        return p

    def ppprint(self):
        return self.pprint([],True,[])

    # basically an inorder traversal
    # really clever
    def pprint(self,pref,isTail,sb):
        if self.rchild:
            t = pref + list("│   " if isTail else "    ")
            self.rchild.pprint(t, False, sb)
        t = pref + list("└── " if isTail else "┌── ") + list(str(self))
        sb.append(t)
        if self.lchild:
            t = pref + list("    " if isTail else "│   ")
            self.lchild.pprint(t, True, sb)
        return sb


@total_ordering        
class End(object):
    def __lt__(self,other):
        return False

BOT = End()    


def rotate_left(p,r):

    p.rchild = r.lchild
    # idiot - don't forget to reset child parent
    if p.rchild != None:
        p.rchild.prnt = p
    r.lchild = p
    # need to adjust child of parent of p
    if p.prnt:
        if p == p.prnt.lchild:
            p.prnt.lchild = r
        else:
            p.prnt.rchild = r

    r.prnt = p.prnt
    p.prnt = r
    p.recalc_size()
    r.recalc_size()


def rotate_right(p,q):    
    p.lchild = q.rchild
    if p.lchild != None:
        p.lchild.prnt = p
    q.rchild = p

    if p.prnt:
        if p.prnt.lchild and p == p.prnt.lchild:
            p.prnt.lchild = q
        else:
            p.prnt.rchild = q
    q.prnt = p.prnt
    p.prnt = q
    p.recalc_size()
    q.recalc_size()


def bubble_up(p):
    while p.prnt and p.prty < p.prnt.prty:
        if p == p.prnt.lchild:
            rotate_right(p.prnt,p)
        else:
            rotate_left(p.prnt,p)

def bubble_down(p):
    while (p.lchild and p.prty > p.lchild.prty) or (p.rchild and p.prty > p.rchild.prty):      
        if p.lchild != None and (p.rchild == None or (p.lchild.prty < p.rchild.prty)):
            rotate_right(p,p.lchild)
        elif p.rchild != None and (p.lchild == None or (p.rchild.prty < p.lchild.prty)):
            rotate_left(p,p.rchild)




def insert(root,key):
    # insert and remove traversal are different: insert needs to 
    # keep going but remove needs to stop
    p = root
    while (p.lchild and key <= p.val) or (p.rchild and key > p.val):
        if p.lchild and key <= p.val:
            p = p.lchild
        else:    
            p = p.rchild

    if key <= p.val:
        nod = node(key,myRand.uniform(0,1),p)    
        p.lchild = nod
    else:   
        nod = node(key,myRand.uniform(0,1),p)    
        p.rchild = nod

    # recalculate tree decorations all the way up to the root
    p = nod
    while p != None: # find root
        p.recalc_size()
        p = p.prnt

    bubble_up(nod) 



def delete(p):
    p.prty = BOT
    bubble_down(p)
    if p.prnt:
        if p.prnt.lchild and p == p.prnt.lchild:
            p.prnt.lchild = None
        else:
            p.prnt.rchild = None

        while p != None: # find root
            p.recalc_size()
            p = p.prnt

    else:
        raise EmptyTreeError


def select(p,i):
    try:
        rank = (p.lchild.size if p.lchild else 0) + 1
    except:
        print(p,i)
    if i == rank:
        return p.val
    elif i < rank:
        return select(p.lchild,i)
    else:
        return select(p.rchild,i - rank)

def remove(root,key):
    p = root
    while (p.lchild and key < p.val) or (p.rchild and key > p.val):
        if p.lchild and key < p.val:
            p = p.lchild
        else:    
            p = p.rchild
    if p.val == key:
        delete(p)
    else:
        raise KeyError
```

Comment: FWIW, I'd be tempted to solve the problem linked with a pair of [heap queues](https://docs.python.org/3/library/heapq.html) split around the median. Trees tend to be slow and error prone.

Comment: @Veedrac Indeed the [solution](https://github.com/makslevental/hackerrank/blob/master/data_structures/balanced_trees/median/soln.py) uses two Bags partitioned around the median (I'm getting time out on the last test case I'm sure because of lines 36,38 in lieu of using a heap).

Comment: That solution doesn't use heaps, which makes rebalancing \$\mathcal{O}(n)\$ instead of \$\mathcal{O}(\log n)\$. My solution uses a [median heap](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15319561/how-to-implement-a-median-heap). Fast deletion is supported by keeping a parallel `Counter`. Deletion only deletes from the `Counter`, and when reading from the heap the top element is popped if it's not in the `Counter`. The heap is rebuilt when half of the elements in it are deleted to prevent its size from blowing up.

Comment: FYI, your `remove_exponent` is way too complex: why not just writing `if x == int(x): x = int(x)`? Division by two is lossless for floats.

Comment: @Veedrac what about 1.50? Maybe such instances don't show up but I wasn't really paying attention to that part of the problem (I stole the remove_exponent code from [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18769210). Thank you for the link to the median heap.

Comment: I'm not sure you mean by "what about 1.50". `1.50 == 1.5`, and `print(1.50)` just outputs `1.5`.

Comment: @Veedrac quite right. Like I said I wasn't paying attention too closely to that part of the problem. I'll keep your suggestion in mind if there's another problem like that.

Answer (score 3):

Try to avoid unnecessary shortening of variable names. `prnt` and `p` should be `parent`, `prty` should probably be `parity`. You should also choose more descriptive variable names than `p`, `q` and `r`.

[PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) recommends `lower_case` for variables (so `is_tail` instead of `isTail`) and `PascalCase` for classes (so `Node` instead of `node`). It also specifies adding a blank after a comma in argument lists like this:

```
def __init__(self, val, prty, prnt=None, lchild=None, rchild=None):
```

Comments like `# idiot - don't forget to reset child parent` should be avoided, or at least modified to `# reset child parent` before putting code up for everyone to see.

`insert(root,key)` and `remove(root,key)` should probably be a method of `Node`.

Use the `@property` decorator for `find_root`:

```
@property
def root(self):
    p = self
    while p.parent != None:
        p = p.parent
    return p
```

This way you can just call `node.root`. However, you never seem to use this method, so delete it.

(There was also a superfluous space after `None:`, which I removed).

Having two methods with the same name but different number of parameters will not work, the last function defined with that name is used (unlike for example in C++). Just use default values (but don't forget that you should never use mutable types as default arguments, see e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132941/least-astonishment-in-python-the-mutable-default-argument)).

```
def pprint(self, pref=None, isTail=True, sb=None):
    """Use inorder traversal to pretty print the tree"""
    pref = [] if not pref else pref
    sb = [] if not sb else sb
    if self.rchild:
        t = pref + list("│   " if isTail else "    ")
        self.rchild.pprint(t, False, sb)
    t = pref + list("└── " if isTail else "┌── ") + list(str(self))
    sb.append(t)
    if self.lchild:
        t = pref + list("    " if isTail else "│   ")
        self.lchild.pprint(t, True, sb)
    return sb
```

(I did not fix the variable names here. You should probably come up with better names than `sb`, though).

You should also add a [`docstring`](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0257/) to your functions to explain what they do and how they are to be used.

Comment: Much appreciated.

Comment: @MaksimLevental You're welcome! Just added a bit more after having another look at your code.